# How to loop jquery GET in another GET on li click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

Im creating an ajax form where if a checkbox is checked, it will query the db with jquery `$.get` and show the results in a div. There will be an `<ul>`with number of pages in the results. I am able to get the results and the number of pages from the php. but when i click on the `<li>` say 2(`<li>2</li>`) i get the second page, but stops there. If I click on 3, nothing happens. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":checkbox").on('change', function() {
      var mygroup = {};
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
            var val = this.value;
            var name = this.name;

            mygroup[name] = (mygroup[name] || []).concat([val]);

        });

        $.get("myresults.php", mygroup, function(data){
            $("#resultdiv").html(data);

            $("#pagesnumbers li").on("click",function(){
                var pageno = $(this).html();
                mygroup["pageno"] = pageno;

                $.get("myresults.php", mygroup, function(data){
                    $("#resultdiv").html(data);
                }) ;
            });

        }) ;
    });
});
```

With this code, i can get the results of any page clicked from the `<li>` only once. If I click any other `<li>` or page number, nothing happens.

I thought of having `.each` for the `<ul>` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":checkbox").on('change', function() {

    var mygroup = {};


        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
            var val = this.value;
            var name = this.name;

            mygroup[name] = (mygroup[name] || []).concat([val]);

        });


        $.get("myresults.php", mygroup, function(data){
            $("#resultdiv").html(data);

            $("#pagesnumbers li").on("click",function(){

                var pageno = $(this).html();

                $(pageno).each(function(){
                    mygroup["pageno"] = pageno;

                    $.get("myresults.php", mygroup, function(data){
                        $("#resultdiv").html(data);
                    }) ;
                });
            });

        }) ;
    });

});
```

Nothing happens with this. Nothing is returned when clicked on any `<li>`. What i want is that the results should appear in the div with page numbers for pagination and when i click on any page / `<li>`, the page should show with the selection of checkboxes intact.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice to see a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Huelfe how can i create a jsfiddle for php and DB?

Comment: php and db are not the problem. Your question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Huelfe, thanks. I want to loop the $.get everytime a `<li>` is clicked .. i tried to create the jsfiddle, but failed to do so on the results. Please help in the looping. I am not sure if i am saying it right, looping. I think not looping but just to run the $.get everytime the li is clicked and pass its value and get the results.

Comment: #1: is it on purpose that you create the $.get without checking the status of the checkbox? In your example the Ajax is triggered on check and uncheck. #2: I would highly recommend to set the listeners (li on click) not in the callback of the ajax-request, but outside and use event delegation. Setting listeners in the callback can lead to undesired behavior.

Comment: @Toni, thanks, yes its on purpose, because if not checked show all results, if checked show results with pagination. But correct me if im doing it wrong. So far everything is working fine, only the pagination part is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments and the final solution

## 1

```
$(":checkbox").on('change', function() {
```

The selector is underspecified. The listener applies to all checkboxes available on your document. You might constrain it by a class or parent element.

## 2

```
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
```

Same as above, plus I can't figure what the idea is behind the checkboxes. From the OP I guessed the checkbox is just the trigger. What we would appreciate is  to see is some of your html structure and the result from the $.get(). Otherwise, we can just guess...

## 3

```
$("#resultdiv").html(data);
```

So, you are creating html within the *.php. Personally, I'd create a JSON object in the php and build the html content in the callback. The JSON would look like:
    data = {
      pages : 23,
      current_page : 2,
      items : {
        [...here go the items...]
      }
    }

If the structure get's large, you can use a js template engine as [doT.js](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html) instead of jquery.

## 4

```
$("#pagesnumbers li").on("click",function(){ // wrong code of OP
```

Again, I would set the listener not in the callback of the $.get(), which is not performant and prone to multi-assignment. Better do it outside and use event delegation, e.g.:

```
$("#resultdiv").on("click", "#pagesnumbers li", function(){ // correct code
```

You can do this outside (e.g. on pageload) and never call it again (assuming your #resultdiv never will be deleted or overwritten, content changing is fine), since it listens for clicks on the #resultdiv and filters for the right elements on click.

## 5, solution to your original problem

```
// wrong code of OP
$.get("myresults.php", mygroup, function(data){
    $("#resultdiv").html(data);

    $("#pagesnumbers li").on("click",function(){
        var pageno = $(this).html();
        mygroup["pageno"] = pageno;

        $.get("myresults.php", mygroup, function(data){
           $("#resultdiv").html(data);
        }) ;
    });

}) ;
```

You have a complicated nesting there. The callback of the **first** $.get sets an event listener on the li which defines a **second** $.get. Actually, the callback of the second one does not invent any listener on the newly written #pagesnumbers (the initial event listener is gone, so it fires only once). This is why nesting is bad ;)
You can prevent this applying the before mentioned scheme.

Comment: I did this, and the `li` in `resultdiv` dont respond to the function if they are echoed from php. The `li` already in the `resultdiv` [before clicking any checkbox] are responding to the function ok. So does echoing the div or the `ul` from `php` becomes deaf for js ? but the styling is applied properly to the `div`. I am looking into configuring the page with JSON, but i don't think that will help. :(

Comment: Css applies to all elements matching the specifiers. Event handlers, if defined as in your example, are per-actual-element. Google direct binding" vs. "event delegation". A direct binding (to e.g. <li>) applies a listener at that time to all elements matchting the specifiers. If later on the DOM changes, the listener expires. Bind the listener to a parent element and delegate. Show your attempt.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8dua1rvL/1/.. I created this only with the jquery. I placed the function and the call to when cliked `<li>` outside, when page loads like you suggested.

Comment: So what am i doing wrong? All i want to do is paginate the results generated by AJAX while still keeping the selection intact. how do i do this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't provide more html. Also you didn't follow the advice of event delegation. https://jsfiddle.net/8dua1rvL/3/ That would give you a start.

Comment: Hey @Toni, it worked mate. Thanks a million. I used your logic to create the functions outside the document.ready and applied the li onclick event targeting the document and div `$(document).on("click", '#pagenumbers li', function(event) { `. I just cant seem to apply the class of active `li` as the page reloads .. il have to do some tweaking in the php itself. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding!